# Javascript for redirecting a page in an A/B test (in Qubit)

Tags: javascript, redirect

Will start this off by saying I'm not a coder, so please be gentle (and treat me like a 3yr old!)
I'm trying to set up an A/B test using Qubit which redirects one page URL to another. I've got the test working, but there is a long lag (at worst about 3 secs) between the standard page loading and the test kicking in to redirect it.

The javascript used in the test is:

```
function execution (options) {  
window.location = 'http://www.halfords.com/advice/cycling/expert-advice/bike-selector'
}

function triggers (options, cb) { 
  const winLoc = window.location.href
  if (winLoc.match(/\/cycling\/bikes\/kids-bikes/i)) {
    cb()
  }
}
```

The test preview link is: http://www.halfords.com/cycling/bikes/kids-bikes#smartserve_preview=1&bypass_segments=&etcForceCreative=524672

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a huge pig of a page. In most browsers, you can press `F12`, then choose the `Network` tab, then click the link above and see what's going on. At first glance I see a lot of images with `lrg` in the name (likely meaning large images), some failed accesses, and one file `base.js` alone taking almost two seconds to load. All these add up to create a very slow page to load.

I don't see any issues with your code above. It's the page itself that's the issue.